# How to get the exact value from function shuffle in codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

Hello im just a newbie in codeigniter and i just want to ask on how to fix this problem...

i just want to make a simple quiz system and i want to shuffle all the questions from my database and display it.. the problem is when i compare the questions choices it gives me a value of unshuffle how can i solve this?

this is my controller to display my questions

```
public function quiz()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $this->load->model('quizmodel');
        $this->data['questions'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
        $this->load->view('client/quiz', $this->data);
    }else{
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```

this is the getQuestions function from my quizmodel

```
public function getQuestions()
{
    $this->db->select("cropscience_id, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, answer");
    $this->db->from("cropscience");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

    $num_data_returned = $query->num_rows;

    if ($num_data_returned < 1) {
      echo "There is no data in the database";
      exit();   
    }
}
```

this is my quiz view

```
<div class="panel-body">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/client_controller/resultdisplay">
    <?php shuffle($questions); ?>
    <?php foreach($questions as $row) { ?>
    <?php $ans_array = array($row->choice1, $row->choice2, $row->choice3, $row->answer);
    shuffle($ans_array); ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p><?=$row->question?></p>
            <br>
            <div class="radio radio-success radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row->cropscience_id ?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>" required>
                <label for="inlineRadio1"> <?=$ans_array[0]?> </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-success radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row->cropscience_id ?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>">
                <label for="inlineRadio1"> <?=$ans_array[1]?> </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio radio-success radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row->cropscience_id ?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>">
                <label for="inlineRadio1"> <?=$ans_array[2]?> </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio radio-success radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row->cropscience_id ?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>">
                <label for="inlineRadio1"> <?=$ans_array[3]?> </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div align="center" >
        <div class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i><input class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded" type="submit" value="Submit!">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

this is my resultdisplay function from my controller

```
public function resultdisplay()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

        $this->load->model('quizmodel');
        $qID = $this->quizmodel->getQuizID();


        $this->data['checks'] = $this->input->post($qID);


        $this->load->model('quizmodel');
        $this->data['results'] = $this->quizmodel->resultsScore();
        $this->load->view('client/result_display', $this->data);

    }else{
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

}
```

this is my result_display view

```
div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 style="color: white;">Results</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<?php $score = 0; ?>
<?php $array1= array(); ?>
<?php $array2= array(); ?>    
<?php $array3= array(); ?>
<?php $array4= array(); ?>
<?php $array5= array(); ?>
<?php $array6= array(); ?>
<?php $array7= array(); ?>
<?php $array8= array(); ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($checks as $checkans) { ?>
    <?php echo $checkans; ?>
    <?php $array1[$count] = $checkans;
           $count++; ?>
<?php }?>
<br><br>

<?php foreach($results as $res) { ?>
       <?php $array2[] = $res->answer; 
             $array3[] = $res->cropscience_id; 
             $array4[] = $res->question; 
             $array5[] = $res->choice1; 
             $array6[] = $res->choice2; 
             $array7[] = $res->choice3; ?>

        <?php } ?>  

        <?php for ($x=0; $x <= $array3[$x]; $x++) { ?>
        <?php echo $array4[$x]; ?>

        <?php if ($array2[$x] != $array1[$x]) { ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-times"></i></p>
                    <p><span style="background-color: #FF9C9E"><?=$array1[$x]?></span></p>
                    <p><span style="background-color: #ADFFB4"><?=$array2[$x]?></span></p>
               </div>

          <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-check"></i></p>
                    <p><span style="background-color: #ADFFB4"><?=$array1[$x]?></span></p>

               </div>
               <?php $score = $score + 1 ?>

        <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>


    <div align="center">

            <input type="hidden" name="score" value="<?=$score?>">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#scoremodal" value="View Your Score">                                            


        <!-- Score Modal Body -->

        <div class="modal inmodal fade" id="scoremodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body" align="center">

                        <h2>Your Score is: </h2>
                        <h1><?=$score?>/100</h1>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <?php echo form_open('client_controller/save_score'); ?>
                        <form method="get">
                        <div align="center">
                            <input type="hidden" name="score" value="<?=$score?>">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ok">
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        <?php   echo form_close(); ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

this is my getQuizID() function model

```
public function getQuizID()
{
    $this->db->select("cropscience_id");
    $this->db->from("cropscience");

    $query = $this->db->get();

}
```

this is my resultsScore() function model

```
public function resultsScore()
{
    $this->db->select("cropscience_id, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, answer");
    $this->db->from("cropscience");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

    $num_data_returned = $query->num_rows;

}
```

please help thank you

Comment: Also specify code for `getQuizID()` and `resultsScore()` of model

Comment: i just updated it sir i put the content of getQuizID and resultsScore

Answer (score 0):

make a query like this:

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'RANDOM');
```

or

```
$this->db->order_by('rand()');
$query = $this->db->get('cropscience');
return $query->result_array();
```